# Problem understanding java code?

Tags: java

I don't understand this code can you explain me

`grid` is an `int[][]`
`distbest` is initialized

```
double distbest
int turn = 60;
if (g > 1)
   this.grid = turn(distbest * turn).grid;
else
   this.grid = turn(-distbest * turn).grid;
```

Comment: What don't you understand about it?

Comment: What piece are you having trouble with? Yeah, we could just explain in detail what every bit of this pretty basic code does - but if you need this, you shouldn't be asking at SO but rather learn about programming basics.

Comment: turn appears to be a method here. Can you find it in your source?

Comment: This listing is missing a large portion of what anyone would need to analyze it. I would suggest posting the full code.

Comment: yes I've just find it I was a little bit confused cause turn was both variable and method It's clear for now Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This section:

```
turn(distbest * turn)
```

means that there's a function `turn` that returns an **object** that contains `grid` that takes a double as a parameter. What's not shown in the code is the return type.

Hence, what I can say, is that the function is declared something like

```
Grid turn(double d);
```

where `Grid` (ficticious) has a `public` attribute of `int[][] grid` (that's why `turn(distbest * turn).grid` is possible).

I'm basing all this from the sample code listed above. The other `turn` is a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

The code is pretty straightforward, so what about it do you not understand?

Perhaps what's confusing you is the double use of `turn` as both a variable name and a method name - `turn(distbest * turn)` is a method call, and the `grid` field of the returned object is the assigned to `this.grid`.

Comment: I didn't know a variable may have a method name. Thank you

Comment: @Christophe: The syntax (specifically the braces after the method name) allows the compiler to distinguish method calls from variable uses, thus it's not necessary to have a single namespace for both.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `turn` variable which is an `int` type, there must also be a `int[][] turn(double)` method which is not shown. It's generally considered bad practice to name methods the same as variables because it causes exactly the type of confusion you're experiencing. If possible, considerer renaming either the variable or the method.